# How to replace NaN from armadillo matrix?

Tags: c++, matlab, armadillo

What is the armadillo/c++ equivalent for the following matlab code?

```
A(isnan(A))=b;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html), you can use [`has_nan()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#has_nan) to see if any of the values is NaN. However, there doesn't seem to be a function to return the indexes of which of them are NaN, so it looks like you may need to loop, and check individual elements one by one.

However, if you are not worried about having infinites, then you could use [`find_nonfinite( X )`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find_nonfinite) that will give you the index of the Inf and NaN values.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a solution that both avoids the loop and let unchanged the Inf values. But as my current datas doesn't contain Inf values, the solution of using find_nonfinite() works perfectly and it writes

    A.elem(find_nonfinite(A)).fill(b);

thank you

Answer (score 8):

Use the [.transform()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#transform) member function to change only the NaN entries. This is also faster than using [find_nonfinite()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#find_nonfinite) and 
it will leave any Inf values unchanged.

```
A.transform( [](double val) { return (std::isnan(val) ? double(b) : val); } );
```

Comment: update: armadillo has the [.replace()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#replace) function

Answer (score 1):

We can use the member function [`replace()`](https://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#replace) to achieve this.

The code is as follows.

```
A.replace(arma::datum::nan, b);
```